# Wrap ng-style in string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have some span which should be hidden if `filters[*index*]` has empty value

```
var span = "<span ng-style='{ 'display': filters[" + filterIndex + "] == '' ? 'none' : 'inline-block' }'></span>"
cell.html(span);
```

And of course it doesn't work

But when it goes to html page, i see this:

```
<span ng-style="{ " display':="" filters[6]="=" ''="" ?="" 'none'="" :="" 'inline-block'="" }'=""></span>
```

How should i wrap `ng-styl`e to see the result i want to see?

Comment: Did you try template strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just ng if for example

```
<div ng-repeat-start="filter in filters track by $index">
     <span ng-if="$index!=null"> {{filter.a}} {{$index}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not code Angular, try something like this:

```
const style = filters[filterIndex] == '' ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
var span = `<span ng-style={ 'display': ${style} }></span>`
```